# Validation Error on null=true fiels in django

Tags: django-models, django-views, html-formfu

I have created a time filed with arguments Null=True in django model, but it is showing validation error(invalid format) while trying to assign the captured empty value

MY time field is optional as per requirement and have to be captured from front end. It is not allowing empty values
code
in model
walkin_time=models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)

in view
try:
newfollowup_lead.walkin_time=request.POST.get('walkin_time', '00:00')
except Exception :
pass

Error
ValidationError at /addfollowupbutton

Comment: Share the full error that's showing. And the entire 'addfollowupbutton` view.